# How to Push Checkbox Item into Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I have a checklist which I am pushing into an input field when the item is checked.
When the item is unchecked, the item gets removed from the Input field.
https://codepen.io/dragoncoderpanda/pen/abWmPgx

However, there is repetition of codes. For each Checkbox, I am having to create an individual function to push/pop the text.

**How do I pass Arguments in my codes so that I don't have to write too many codes repetitively?**

```
itemArray = [];
let inputField = document.querySelector('.inputField')
let itemOne = document.querySelector('#itemOne')

itemOne.addEventListener('click', alpha);

function alpha(){
  if(itemOne.checked == true){
    itemArray.push(itemOne.name);
    inputField.placeholder = itemArray;
    inputField.value = itemArray;
  } else{
    itemArray.pop(itemOne.name);
    inputField.placeholder = itemArray;
    inputField.value = itemArray;
  }
}

let itemTwo = document.querySelector('#itemTwo')
itemTwo.addEventListener('click', beta);
function beta(){
  if(itemTwo.checked == true){
    itemArray.push(itemTwo.name);
    inputField.placeholder = itemArray;
    inputField.value = itemArray;
  } else{
    itemArray.pop(itemTwo.name);
    inputField.placeholder = itemArray;
    inputField.value = itemArray;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just listen for a change event on all relevant checkboxes, then loop through the `:checked` ones to build your `itemArray` each time.

```js
itemArray = [];
let inputField = document.querySelector('.inputField')
let chks = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]')

chks.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', e => {
  itemArray = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked').forEach(chk => itemArray.push(chk.getAttribute('name')))
  inputField.value = itemArray.join(", ")
}))
```

```html
<input class='inputField' />
<div class='checkboxes'>
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='chk1' value='1' /> Chk 1 </label>
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='chk2' value='2' /> Chk 2 </label>
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='chk3' value='3' /> Chk 3 </label>
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='chk4' value='4' /> Chk 4 </label>
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='chk5' value='5' /> Chk 5 </label>
</div>
```